# Null value given when confirming email's

Tags: php, user-registration

**Fixed the problem by adding `if ( 'email' == $type || 'email2' == $type ) {` to the top of the snippet below and changing the first elseif to a if statment**

I have created a WordPress register form on the homepage of my WordPress but I am having a little problem with verifying the email address match.

This is the code I am using to do that.

```
elseif ( !is_email($userdata['user_email'], true) )
$error = __('You must enter a valid email address.', 'frontendprofile');
elseif ( email_exists($userdata['user_email']) )
$error = __('Sorry, that email address is already used!',     'frontendprofile');
elseif ( !empty($_POST['email'] ) && !empty( $_POST['email2'] ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['email'] == $_POST['email2'] )
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->id,      'user_email' =>     esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) ) );
    else
        $error = __('The emails you entered do not match.  Your    email was not updated.', 'frontendprofile');
}
```

But I keep getting this error when I hit the register button

```
Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in
```

I take it that some how the verfication process isn't working fully so it is not taking the email address and instead showing a null value in the form submit, but I can't see where this is happening.

Comment: Are possibly using the global `$current_user` object without having made it accessible first? If so, add the line `global $current_user;` on top of the above snippet...

Comment: @JohannesPille Just tried that but doesn't seem to have helped....struggling with this one ive got a feeling its to do with the email verification code somehow.

Comment: Then you will have to expand the snippet of code shown - the Warning you get is from PHP directly and not from WP. And in the snippet given, the only object present is `$current_user`...

Comment: @JohannesPille Ive put it in a pastebin if you could take a quick look? http://pastebin.com/Bq59dMmT

Comment: Firstly, thats a warning not an error, and secondly, it's incomplete "Bob: I once starred in a film called. Alice: Yes? Go on... Which film?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this isn't an error, it's a warning. If it's causing a page crash rather than a logic bug, thats because you're printing your error log to the screen, not logging it to a log file as you should be doing. Turning off display errors should fix this.

This still leaves you with the warning, and those are still bad. Notice in your code you take the POST vars, and escape them, but you don't do any check on what the value is. E.g. the form fields might be empty, or `''`/`null` and they'd still pass through.

I suggest you reverse the order of your check, you need to check if the email is set first, then if it's empty, **then**, once you've verified that there is actually something to check against, do you check that it's the correct format of an email. Right now you're doing it in the opposite order.

edit: Just to clarify your code should do:

```
if email is not empty then
     if email is not valid
          error = '...'
     else
         if email1 == email 2 then
             wp_update_user
         else
             error = '...'
```

Check if the email is empty before doing anything with it.

What you're actually doing is:

```
if email is not valid then <- oh dear, we haven't checked if email is set/empty, error/warning
    error = '...'
else if email is not empty then < -- too late, we've already used the email value!
    if email1 == email2 then
        wp_update_user
```

Comment: If I remove the code which is in my original answer so it doesn't check if the emails match then the user will be registered fine with all the info it is something due to the email verify.

Comment: As I said, the checks are in the wrong order. If the email is null, then you should check, but by the time you reach that check, you've already used the data in `is_email`!

Comment: I've ellaborated in my edited answer. Check then use data. Don't use data then check afterwards.

Comment: Can you expand on the code a bit please I still cant get it to work think I may be setting it out wrong.

Comment: Managed to figure it out by adding this line at the top `if ( 'email' == $type || 'email2' == $type ) {`